# How to Detect browsers installed in a system

Tags: java, browser

Using Java, how can I detect all of the browsers that are installed on a system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

You *can* open a page using the default browser on a system with Java 6 *, but you can't list all browsers installed on a system.

Sure, you can iterate over Windows' `C:\Program Files\` folder or *nix's `/usr/local` (or other dirs) to check for browser names, but you might run into user-privilege issues and you're never guaranteed to get all browsers, nor is this OS independent.

- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/

Comment: If you knew the OS I guess you could check for existence of the various browser exe's in all the usual places? Not bullet proof by any means, but might suffice.

Comment: @Richard, I was just editing while you posted that comment. I agree: there's no "fool proof" solution.

Comment: What is "usual places"? In Linux/Unix world, there is no such thing as "usual place". Some may install it in /bin, /usr/bin/, /opt/, /usr/local/bin/, /home/username/browser/, etc... and many distro mixes them up. Even in Windows, it's possible to install a program not in Program Files.

Comment: @Lie Ryan, but in Windows, you can search for a specific browser in the registry. IE, for one, definitely uses the Registry, so I guess that is the "usual places" the OP was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

For windows you can get this in formation from registry:

To get this information from java.

1) create batch file browsers.bat with following script.

echo Browsers> browsers.txt
for /f "skip=4 delims=" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet" 2^>nul') do (
        echo %%~nA 1>>browsers.txt
        )
exit

2) Invoke the batch file from java using following command.
Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start browsers.bat", null, new File("C:\Users\batch-file-path"));

This will store all the available browsers in browsers.txt file.

Comment: The OP say **Using java** , so that is not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can detect ALL browsers installed on a system but you could check whether a specific one is installed by looking in the registry

Comment: This will only work for windows, and at that you may run into permissions issues or be redirected to the virtual store in which case you will get nothing.

Comment: Java and registry? What about *nix systems or MacOS, these don't have a registry.